# C#: Why does my list not print the items?

Tags: c#, list, random, printing

I'm trying to print out the int items inside the list but I get the following output, which is obviously not what I want to print:

```
YSolution.Dice
YSolution.Dice
YSolution.Dice
YSolution.Dice
YSolution.Dice
```

Source code:

```
class Dice
{
    //defining variable and properties
    private bool _hold = false;

    private Random rnd;
    public int Current { get; private set; }

    public bool IsHolding
    {
        get { return _hold; }
        set { _hold = value; }
    }

public Dice()
    {
        Current = 0;
        rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        FRoll();
    }

    public int FRoll()
    {
        Current = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        return Current;
    }



class DiceCup
    {
        public List<Dice> Dices { get; } = new List<Dice>();

        public DiceCup(int count)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Dices.Add(new Dice());
            }

            foreach (Dice aDice in Dices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aDice);
            }
        }
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DiceCup nbd = new DiceCup(count);



    }
}
```

The method FRoll(); seem to not get called in the dice class for some reason, when a new item is added to the list.I really just want to print out the items in the List Dices but I do not get the output/result I want. Anyone who can spot the error?

Comment: Console.WriteLine is using the `ToString` in Dice to print the Class name and location. You could override the `ToString` method in the Dice Class to return the Current property. Documentation for overriding `ToString` can be found here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're just calling `ToString()` on your `Dice` object.  Since you haven't overriden `ToString()` this is just using the default `object.ToString()` implementation which returns the type name of the object (`YSolution.Dice` in your case).

You have a `Current` property on your dice that returns the value of the dice, if you call this method then that will return the value of the dice, which you can then print: change `Console.WriteLine(aDice);` to `Console.WriteLine(aDice.Current);`.

Alternatively, as others have pointed out, [you can override `ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) on your `Dice` class to return the current value of the dice:

```
class Dice
{
    //defining variable and properties
    private bool _hold = false;

    private Random rnd;
    public int Current { get; private set; }

    public bool IsHolding
    {
        get { return _hold; }
        set { _hold = value; }
    }

    public Dice()
    {
        Current = 0;
        rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        FRoll();
    }

    public int FRoll()
    {
        Current = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        return Current;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Current.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to implement the ToString-method:

```cs
public string ToString()
{
  return Current.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides overriding the `ToString` method, as mentioned in other answers, you could also collect the results from the dice and print those:

```cs
foreach (int result in Dices.Select(d => d.Current))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method is defined in the `System.Linq` namespace.